# C++ Local object goes out of scope returning a pointer (memory allocated using new). Memory leak because of this

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

There is a memory leak reported in this function. I'm not able to figure why this isn't freeing the memory?

Sample code:

```
void Somefunction(){
    Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();
    /*...
      ...some processing using dangler
      ...*/
    delete dangler;
}
```

---

```
Object1* StaticClass::myFunc(){
    LocalObj lc;
    lc.another();
    return lc.get();
}
```

---

```
Class lc{
    Object1* m_dangler;
    void another(){
        m_danlger = new Object1();
    }
    Object1* get(){
        return m_danlger;
    }
}
```

This `delete danlger;` is not working and i'm seeing a memory leak at `Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();`

The questions are:
1) Why am I not able to delete when the pointer `danlger` is indeed pointing to the location.
2) If this is not the correct way to free memory, where am I going wrong and what is the correct way?

Comment: The "correct way" is to avoid direct memory allocations where possible, and to use smart pointers when possible.

Comment: But in that case, I won't be able to use the data after `Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();`

Comment: This is not even valid C++ code. Please post real code, instead of imaginary code. "Somefunction{
    Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();
    ...
    ...
    delete dangler;
}" -- that's neither a function declaration, nor a class declaration. Only you know what this is supposed to be.

Comment: There is no memory leak in the code you've shown us.

Comment: @SreecharanDesabattula: That is incorrect.

Comment: @SreecharanDesabattula your "sample" code show absolutely no need for allocating anything with `new` or using `delete`. Just `Object1 notdangler;` will work great in that case. Show us *real* code that does need an object that lives past the scope of where it is created and we might be able to help better.

Comment: If I can post real code, I will. But I can't. This is not a class project/practice, I'm looking at a really huge code base and I'm supposed to fix this single memory leak.
And yes, there is memory leak reported at `Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();`

Comment: @SreecharanDesabattula that is why you should create a [mcve] and post that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is surprisingly simple: *every* `new` must be balanced with a `delete`.

If your code doesn't balance these exactly then you have undefined behaviour or a memory leak. In your case that's trivial to check with your line by line debugger.

One of your problems with the `lc` class is that it's possible to copy it (using the compiler generated copy constructor) which will shallow copy the pointer member. It becomes difficult to track which object, if any, "owns" the memory allocated by `another`.

You could attempt to polish this class. But really, you may as well ditch the whole thing and use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead, depending on your specific requirements. Those classes manage the `delete` for you and (unless you use them perversely) *guarantee* that `new`s and `delete`s are balanced.

Comment: Exactly.Every new should be present with delete.

Comment: Indeed. But one day, if `lc` is retained, it will happen. Yet another problem.

Comment: I do realize that every new should be balanced with a delete. In my use case, after `Object1 * dangler = StaticClass::myFunc();`, I have some processing to do with `dangler`. If I use delete in destructor of lc, I won't be able to access the data in `m_dangler` at all.

Comment: In which case I haven't grasped why you *need* the `lc` class.

Comment: `lc` exists and is legacy code. The code here is just a sample. The actual code is really huge and much of it cannot be redesigned in my power.